# Renaming jpg to jpeg in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am looking to rename all files from .jpg to .jpeg if they exist in the column.

structure:

- tables: table1, table2, ...

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| image1.jpg | id1 |
| image2.jpg | id2 |
| image3.jpeg | id3 |
|  | id4 |

Change image1.jpg to image1.jpeg in table1, column1 for the entire column, where some rows may not have the image and some files may already be in the jpeg format

I am very new to mysql, and basically only know how to query and change on a one by one basis, So I am also not sure if this can even be done, but I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please post sample data for the table(s) in question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I made an edit renaming values to data, which I am assuming you were looking for, unless I misunderstood

Comment: Please post 5 rows from the input table.  You have not already done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE column value, with use of REPLACE() MySQL function

```
UPDATE table
SET column = REPLACE(column, '.jpg', '.jpeg')
WHERE column LIKE '%.jpg'
```

this way you can update column value end with .jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`like`](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_like.asp) to find all rows where column1 ends in `.jpg`. Then use [`regexp_replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) to change from `.jpg` to `.jpeg`.

Make sure to escape the `.` in the regex else it will be interpreted as "any character" and will match, for example, "foofjpg". You must use `\\` because `\` is the escape character in strings.

```
update some_table
set column1 = regexp_replace(column1, '\\.jpg$', '.jpeg') 
where column1 like '%.jpg'
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/gaJaC4Vz).